# NuGet pack trying to use strange path and can't therefore find the build output: NU5012

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

So, I have a .csproj file that is targeting .NET Standard, .NET Core and .NET Framework: https://github.com/dhilgarth/ReadGitVersionInformation/blob/master/src/ReadGitVersionInformation.csproj

I want to create a NuGet package from that project file and are therefore running the following command inside the folder which contains the project file (this folder is named `src`):

```
NuGet.exe pack ReadGitVersionInformation.csproj
```

The result of this command line is this:

> Attempting to build package from 'ReadGitVersionInformation.csproj'.
>   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.7.179.6572' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
>   **Error NU5012: Unable to find 'bin\Debug\src\bin\Debug\'. Make sure the project has been built.**

It is looking for the nonsensical pack `bin\Debug\src\bin\Debug`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dotnet pack` to pack SDK-based project files. (e.g. `dotnet pack -c Release`)

`nuget.exe pack` is used only for legacy csproj files.